# Multi-module Maven and Spring Boot project doesn´t generate fat executable jar for secondary module

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have a multi module Maven / Spring Boot (v2.3.3) application implemented as follow:

```
my-project (pom)
  \__ my-api (jar)   - rest api controllers
   \__ my-core (jar) - entities, repositories and service beans
    \__ my-db (jar)  - DB migration (with Mongock)
```

The project and application runs and works fine, no big deal. The "my-api" module has got a main spring boot application class that runs the API as usual.

The thing is, recently I added the "my-db" module to implement MongoDB migration to automate in my CI deployment. The "my-db" module also has got another main spring boot application class, which is a stand-alone application that runs the migration process and I want to automate in my CI environment.

The problem is that my maven build does not generate a fat executable JAR for the "my-db" module, only for the "my-api" module.

Am I missing something?

my-project pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

my-api pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <finalName>my-api</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>my.ApiApplication</mainClass>
                <executable>true</executable>
                <layout>JAR</layout>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <skip>false</skip>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

my-core pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

my-db pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <start-class>my.DbMigrationApp</start-class>
</properties>

<build>
    <finalName>my-db</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this configuration was missing in the plugin block from "my-db" pom file.

```
<configuration>
    <skip>false</skip>
</configuration>
```